# How to merge consecutive rows of date and time using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a following table (view)

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+
| Data  |    Date     |    Time     |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
| Data1 |  2020-08-19 |    13:00:00 |
| Data1 |  2020-08-19 |    13:30:00 |
| Data1 |  2020-08-19 |    14:00:00 |
| Data1 |  2020-08-21 |    07:00:00 |
| Data1 |  2020-08-21 |    07:30:00 |
| Data2 |  2020-08-20 |    08:00:00 |
| Data2 |  2020-08-20 |    08:30:00 |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

I am trying to find out a way to create an SQL statement that would do the following: merge data with consecutive date and time (30 mins interval)

From my basic to early intermediate competence in SQL, I fail to use correctly the GROUP BY. Looking forward for answers or directions.
Many thanks again

The result should be:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+
| Data  |     Date    |    Time     |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
| Data1 |  2020-08-19 |    13:00:00 |
| Data1 |  2020-08-21 |    07:00:00 |
| Data2 |  2020-08-20 |    08:00:00 |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: *"merge data"* - you need to define the merge rules.

Comment: What is MySQL version precisely?

Comment: Mysql version is 8.0.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `LAG()` window function:

```
select Data, Date, Time
from (
  select *,
      concat(Date, ' ', Time) - interval 30 minute <= 
      lag(concat(Date, ' ', Time)) over (partition by Data order by Date, Time) flag
  from tablename  
) t
where coalesce(flag, 0) = 0
order by Data, Date, Time
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a51881139a5856db6150a4fd27b74185).
Results:

```
> Data  | Date       | Time    
> :---- | :--------- | :-------
> Data1 | 2020-08-19 | 13:00:00
> Data1 | 2020-08-21 | 07:00:00
> Data2 | 2020-08-20 | 08:00:00
```

Comment: Nice it works. Could I ask something if I try these SQL in MariaDB is it still working?

Comment: @StoledInk MariaDB wants casting of the datetime string to datetime: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=2b24f87c3975baeb6e5aa85967b7e2c6

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions. The idea is to create groups of adjacent records using a window sum that increments every time the difference between two consecutive records is more than 30 minutes.

```
select data, min(dt) start_dt,max(dt) end_dt, count(*) cnt
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(lag_dt is not null and dt > lag_dt + interval 30 minute)
            over(partition by data order by dt) grp
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            lag(dt) over(partition by data order by dt) lag_dt
        from (
            select t.*, concat(date, ' ', time) dt 
            from mytable t
        ) t
    ) t
) t
group by data, grp
order by min(dt)
```

Note that storing date and time in two separate columns is not a good practice; I added an extra level of nesting to generate `datetime` values.

We can eliminate one level of nesting with date arithmetics (here, the interval must be exactly 30 minutes):

```
select data, min(dt) start_dt,max(dt) end_dt, count(*) cnt
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by data order by dt) rn
    from (
        select t.*, concat(date, ' ', time) dt 
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by data, dt - interval (rn * 30) minute
order by min(dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated for postgres

```
select Data, Date, Time
from (
  select *,
      Date+ Time - interval '00:30' <= 
      lag(Date+ Time,1) over (partition by Data order by Date+Time) flag
  from tablename  
) T
where flag is null or  flag is false
order by Data, Date, Time
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bd20ddcda3dae522cba630b71d46f2fd)